# beginning next month, beginning next semester, beginning this year ... etc

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs, ellipsis

Example:

> **Beginning next month**, Dining Services will no longer serve hot breakfast foods at university dining halls.

Is **Beginning next month** an example of ellipsis?

Does it means some complete sentence?

Such as

> **Next month begins.**

or

> Dining Services **begin next month.**

Comment: It doesn't mean either of those things. The new arrangements (that hot breakfasts will not be served) will start next month - that is, for the rest of _this_ month you can still get a hot breakfast.

Comment: @KateBunting So the subject of "will start next mont" is omitted without explanation?

Comment: The subject of _beginning next month_ is the new arrangements of 'Dining Services no longer serving hot breakfasts'.

Comment: @KateBunting I meant that the original sentence I provided which don't express explicitly subject part that I didn't understand. I was sure your explanation in the earlier commet is clearly understood to know the subject.

Comment: I don't see that anything is 'omitted without explanation'. The subject is 'Dining Services' - they are going to stop serving hot breakfasts, and the arrangement will begin next month.

Comment: I got it wrong before. Thanks

Comment: Is your question about *what subordinate clause is represented by "beginning next month"* or about *whether "beginning next month" is an example of ellipsis*?

Comment: Oh.. Yes. The question is about subordinate clause.